# In JavaScript, why is []==false true?

Tags: javascript

`!![]` is `true` while `!!false` is absolutely `false`. Why does `[]==false` evaluate to `true` in JavaScript?

Comment: You might like this comparison table with the == operator https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: The only proper answer to that question is this video: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat 
and then maybe also this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et8xNAc2ic8

Comment: The answer to your question is what are you trying to compare by using == operator?

Answer (score 1):

`==` does some type conversions before comparing. If you don't want to do the type conversion use `===` instead.

```js
document.write([]==false); //true
document.write('<br>');
document.write([]===false); //false
```